# Corda - Recording Particular States in a Transaction

Tags: corda

In Corda, when receiving finality, we can specify which states to record:

Relevant states...

```
ReceiveFinalityFlow(session, statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ONLY_RELEVANT)
```

All states...

```
ReceiveFinalityFlow(session, statesToRecord = StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE)
```

There's no in between. What it we wanted to store only states of a particular type?

For example...

```
ReceiveFinalityFlow(session) {
    record { tx.outputsOfType<Foo>() }
    ignore { tx.outputsOfType<Bar>() }
}
```

Is, or could this be possible in future?

Comment: I forwarded your question internally, hopefully we can get an answer on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding after a bit of conversation internally that this just isn't supported in Corda. For what it's worth you're not the only one to suggest this feature.

Comment: Thanks, David. I did a bit of digging into the code that records transactions and their states to see if this sort of functionality would have to be baked into Corda itself, or could be designed as a 3rd party API. No such luck as yet, but I'll keep investigating.